# ansible return code 0 for action but still getting NO MORE HOSTS LEFT

Tags: pip, ansible, yum, ansible-2.x

ansible 2.1.2.0

```
- name: Ensure/Install pre-requisite packages (RedHat)
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: installed
    update_cache: yes
  with_items:
    - 'pygpgme'
    - 'yum-utils'
    - 'python-pip'
    - 'facter'
```

When I'm running my plabook, it errors out even when the return status/code **rc** is **0** and if i turn on the debug (-vvv), the whole **ok:...** output comes in Green color (instead of Red color which is for a failed step/action).

Questions:

1. Why am I getting this `NO MORE HOSTS LEFT` error, when  **"rc": 0** and whole output color is coming in Green for localhost. All the packages are already installed. See output at the bottom.
2. How can I do this in Ansible (if possible without using `command`/`shell` modules) `sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only`, is that possible via `yum` module (if possible in that same `yum` action I have in my playbook)?

So, to fix it, I also tried running yum to install packages/pending  at command line (and it shows Nothing to do as everything is up to date):

```
$ sudo yum install yum-utils pygpgme python-pip facter
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.hoobly.com
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirror.spro.net
 * updates: mirror.tocici.com
Package yum-utils-1.1.31-40.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package pygpgme-0.3-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python2-pip-8.1.2-5.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Package facter-2.4.1-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Re-ran the ansible playbook and it errored again with the same issue.

```
TASK [company.company-ansible : Ensure/Install pre-requisite packages (RedHat)] ***
task path: /home/vagrant/aks/ansible/tasks/yum_install.yml:3
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438 `" ) && sleep 0'
<localhost> PUT /tmp/tmpxzRchU TO /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438/yum
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438/ /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438/yum && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-bteisecjvsnsqhbbsohdrpswvjynpydi; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438/yum; rm -rf "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1483049236.46-121920804274438/" > /dev/null 2>&1'"'"' && sleep 0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'pygpgme', u'yum-utils', u'python-pip', u'facter']) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"conf_file": null, "disable_gpg_check": false, "disablerepo": null, "enablerepo": null, "exclude": null, "install_repoquery": true, "list": null, "name": ["pygpgme", "yum-utils", "python-pip", "facter"], "state": "installed", "update_cache": true, "validate_certs": true}, "module_name": "yum"}, "item": ["pygpgme", "yum-utils", "python-pip", "facter"], "msg": "The following packages have pending transactions: python2-pip-noarch", "rc": 0, "results": ["pygpgme-0.3-9.el7.x86_64 providing pygpgme is already installed", "yum-utils-1.1.31-40.el7.noarch providing yum-utils is already installed"]}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/vagrant/aks/ansible/company-ansible.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Ansible's `yum` module doesn't support that 2nd bullet 2. So, I had to use `command` module (which I was not preferring to use earlier) as that will resolve the error.

```
- name: Yum complete transaction cleanup only
  command: sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
```

or better to use,

```
- name: Yum complete transaction cleanup only
  command: yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only
  become_user: root
```

Still, question 1 is left unanswered as why when `rc = 0` / output is in Green color, then ansible playbook action failed.

Comment: If I remember correctly `NO MORE HOSTS LEFT` was a bug which was fixed in Ansible 2.1.3.

Comment: is there a solution for mac as well? facing the same thing on mac.